# wsgen ant task ignore @webMethod(exclude=true) annotation

Tags: java, web-services, ant, jax-ws, wsgen

I Have a web service implementation class in java and I use wsgen to generate the service end point classes. There is a public method in my SEI that I want to exclude from the web-service interface. It seems that the annotation

```
@WebMethod (exclude=true)
```

is meant to do that but it does not seem to work with the wsgen ant task.

Comment: Thanks! BTW: The common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like [Issue #789](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=789) (bug in wsgen). Maye give the suggested workaround a try:

> As a temporary workaround with old impl, you can try removing the @WebMethod on non-excluded 
>   methods.