# How can I hide a method in a javabean from appearing in the wsdl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl

I have a java bean class say

```
class LineInfoBean{
  //Methods 

   method a() //Appears in the wsdl definition

   ....
   ....

   method b()//Appears in the wsdl definition -> I want to hide it from appearing in the wsdl


}
```

Is there a way to hide method b from appearing in the wsdl definition . I tried using annotation `@WebMethod(exclude=true)` on the method but it does not work .Is there some way to hide this method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245791/wsgen-ant-task-ignore-webmethodexclude-true-annotation

Comment: Can't you make method b() private?

Comment: Nope , it has to be public . And yet I want to make the method hidden in the wsdl

Answer (score -1):

Don't put @WebMethod annotation on this method but put it on other methods that should appear in WSDL